# On the electric field created by a conductor

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, conductors

The electric field created by a conductor at a point $M$ extremely close to it is $\vec{E}=\vec{E_1}+\vec{E_2}$ where $\vec{E_1}$ is the electric field created by such a tiny bit of the conductor that we can suppose it to be a plane, and since $M$ is extremely close to the conductor such that the distance is really small compared to the size of the plane we further ahead assimilate it to an infinite plane and hence $\vec{E_1}=\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}$ and this is where I block, when we use Gauss' law on an infinite plane we also account for the electric fields on the other side of the cylinder (here our gaussian surface), but in the case of the conductor the electric field inside of it would be $\vec{0}$ and so $\vec{E_1}$ should be $\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0}$.
I cannot see where I've gone wrong.

Comment: Why would E = 0 in your calc?

Comment: conductor in electrostatic equilibrium

Comment: That does not answer my question.

Comment: Well in a conductor which is in electrostatic equilibrium the electric field inside is 0

Comment: No kidding.  You are NOT calculating the E INSIDE the material but in the space around it.  Also, what do you mean by "equilibrium".  Not uncharged I hope.  At a constant potential.

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. When you take a cylinder as the gaussian surface to find the $\vec{E}$ near the conductor well it (the cylinder) has an end inside of it (the conductor), and the $\vec{E}.\vec{dA}$ inside would be $0$ since $\vec{E}=0$ inside right?

Comment: Your use of words is very confusing.  The cylinder is not "inside" the conductor, it cuts through.  The surfaces on which you are calculating the flux are not inside the conductor.

Comment: If you are taking the cylinder to be partially inside the conducting medium and partially outside then you may have a zero contribution from one side but not the other.  And if the Gaussian surface is completely immersed in the conductor then yes, E = 0 and Q_inside = 0 and all is well.  I am more confused about the problem now.  Sorry.

Comment: I meant partially inside and so as you said "then you may have a zero contribution from one side but not the other" so we end up with $E\pi r^2+0+0=\frac{\sigma\pi r^2}{\epsilon_0}$

Comment: Something like that but you only now have half the charge contained in the Gaussian surface, make sure you account for that.

Comment: To quote the accepted answer "The sheet charge density $\sigma$ is related to the total charge residing on both surfaces of a piece of conducting sheet", in our case, since the conductor is at a constant potential i.e $E$ inside is $0$ and thus the charges are on the surface we mean on the "outer-side" of it?

Comment: I'm not following here, can you please explain further?

Comment: Your equation will give the wrong answer because you have one end of your surface inside the conductor and the standard treatment has both flat ends outside.  There are 2 outer surfaces of the conducting sheet contained within the Gaussian cylinder in the standard treatment.  You have 1/2 of that.

Comment: I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not alone about being confused about this topic and in part is is because of the use the same symbol $\sigma$ being used to mean two different things; sheet charged density and surface charge density.

On the HyperPhysics website there is a derivation [Electric Field: Sheet of Charge](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/elesht.html) as shown below

[image]

The **sheet** charge density $\sigma$ is related to the **total** charge residing on both surfaces of a piece of conducting sheet **not** the charge residing on one surface of a piece of conducting sheet.

Note that $\sigma$ has not been called the **surface** charge density in the HyperPhyics derivation.

---

Let me change the definition of a symbol.
In the diagram below the sheet charge density is $\Sigma$ per unit area.

[image]

So the total charge on the sheet (with charges residing above and below the sheet) is $\Sigma A$.

In this case the **surface** charge density is $\sigma = \dfrac{\Sigma A}{2A} = \dfrac {\Sigma}{2}$

---

In your example you are dealing with only one surface which has a surface charge density which is double the surface charge density that was used in the HyperPhysics derivation and so you should expect the electric field to be twice as large.

Comment: Although I accepted the answer I still would like to restate my problem :
When you take a cylinder as the gaussian surface to find the $\vec{E}$ near the conductor well it (the cylinder) has an end inside of it (the conductor), and the $\vec{E}.\vec{dA}$ inside would be $0$ since $\vec{E}=0$ inside right?

Comment: @archaic Yes so the total flux through the two ends of the Gaussian cylinder is $\sigma A+0$ and the total charge within the Gaussian cylinder is $\sigma A$.

Comment: Yes well it's not supposed to be that, the whole field created by the conductor should be equal to that but the contribution from the element of surface close to our point (the one we're assimilating to be an infinite sheet) should be $\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}$ and this is why I'm confused

Comment: @archaic Does not the “plane” that you are considering have the same thickness as the rest of the conductor?

Comment: yes of course .